# how a option tag value selected can be retrieved in two or more jsp pages

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, jsp, servlets

purchase.jsp

```
 <form action="view.jsp" method="post">
    <select id='category'>
    <option value=""> Make a selection </option>
    <option value='company'>company</option>
    <option value='institution'>institution</option>
    <option value='hospital'>hospital</option>
    <option value='Others'>Others</option>
    </select>
    <input type = "submit" value="Submit"
    </form>
```

view.jsp

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function setAction(nPage){

            document.forms[0].action = nPage;
        }
    </script>
<form>
    <select onchange="setAction(this.value)">
    <option value=''> Make a selection </option>
    <option value='PDF2.jsp'> PDF</option>
    <option value='XLS2.jsp'> XLS </option>
    <option value='DOC.jsp'> DOC </option>
    <option value='XLSX2.jsp'> XLSX </option>
    </select>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

At first i will select *company* from `purchase.jsp` and i will click *submit*,it will go to `view.jsp` and i will again select `PDF2.jsp`, and click *submit* it will go to `PDF2.jsp` page.Now My question is how to print  *company* that i selected in `purchase.jsp` to `PDF2.jsp`. So here there are 3 jsp pages and the value selected in first jsp page should be printed in third jsp page but the sequence should go from first jsp(`purchase.jsp`) to second jsp(`view.jsp`) and from second jsp(`view.jsp`) to third jsp(`PDF2.jsp`).

PDF2.jsp

```
<body>
<form>
<%
String cat=request.getParameter("category");
System.out.println("It is" +cat);
%>
</form>
</body>
```

Comment: One option is to store it in hidden value.

Comment: can store it in session variable

Comment: @charlietfl Yeah it can be stored in session variable.Just Now i too realised that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

purchase.jsp

```
<form action="view.jsp" method="post">
<select name="category">
<option value=""> Make a selection </option>
<option value="company">company</option>
<option value="institution">institution</option>
<option value="hospital">hospital</option>
<option value="Others">Others</option>
</select>

<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>

</form>
```

view.jsp

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function setAction(nPage){

        document.forms[0].action = nPage;
    }
</script>
<form>
<% 
String category=request.getParameter("category");
session.setAttribute("cat",category);
%>
<select onchange="setAction(this.value)">
<option value=''> Make a selection </option>
<option value='PDF2.jsp'> PDF</option>
<option value='XLS2.jsp'> XLS </option>
<option value='DOC.jsp'> DOC </option>
<option value='XLSX2.jsp'> XLSX </option>
</select>
<br/>

<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

PDF2.jsp

```
<body>
<% 
Connection conn = null;

try 
{ 
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/marketing_database","root","root");
    String jrxmlFile ="D:/dev/tools/jasper files/report10.jrxml";
    InputStream input = new FileInputStream(new File(jrxmlFile));
    JasperDesign jasperDesign = JRXmlLoader.load(input);

    System.out.println("Compiling Report Designs");
    JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jasperDesign);

    System.out.println("Creating JasperPrint Object");
    Map parameters = new HashMap();
    parameters.put("category",session.getAttribute("cat"));
    JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport,parameters,conn);
    byte bytes[] = new byte[10000]; 
    JRPdfExporter exporter = new JRPdfExporter();
    ByteArrayOutputStream PDFStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); 
    exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jasperPrint); 
    exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, PDFStream); 
    exporter.exportReport(); 
    System.out.println("Size of byte array:"+PDFStream.size()); 
    bytes = PDFStream.toByteArray(); 
    response.setContentType("application/pdf"); 
    System.out.println("After JasperPrint = 1"); 
    response.setContentLength(bytes.length); 
    System.out.println("After JasperPrint = 2"); 
    PDFStream.close(); 
    System.out.println("After JasperPrint = 3"); 

    OutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream(); 
    System.out.println("After JasperPrint = 4"); 
    outputStream.write(bytes, 0, bytes.length); 
    outputStream.flush(); 
    outputStream.close(); 

}
catch(Exception e) 
{e.printStackTrace();} 

%>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

In view.jsp,set it into session like this

```
<%
session.setAttribute("category",category);
%>
```

You can retrieve it in any other jsp like this

```
String company= (String)session.getAttribute("category");
```